# How to use javascript async/await on executing shell script

Tags: javascript, shell, async-await

So I have a server listening to RabbitMQ requests:

```
        console.log(' [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C', q);
        channel.consume(q, async function reply(msg) {
            const mongodbUserId = msg.content.toString();
            console.log(' [x] Received %s', mongodbUserId);

            await exec('./new_user_run_athena.sh ' + mongodbUserId, function(
                error,
                stdout,
                stderr
            ) {
                console.log('Running Athena...');
                console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
            });

            console.log(
                ' Finished running Athena for mongodbUserId=%s',
                mongodbUserId
            );

            channel.sendToQueue(
                msg.properties.replyTo,
                new Buffer(mongodbUserId),
                { correlationId: msg.properties.correlationId }
            );

            channel.ack(msg);
        });
```

The problem is that the await call on executing the shell script `new_user_run_athena.sh` happens after I print out `Finished running Athena for mongodbUserId`. You can see it happening in the console log:

```
 [*] Waiting for messages in run_athena_for_new_user_queue. To exit press CTRL+C
 [x] Received 5aa96f36ed4f68154f3f2143
 Finished running Athena for mongodbUserId=5aa96f36ed4f68154f3f2143
Running Athena...
stdout: 
stderr:
```

Is it even possible to use async await syntax on executing a shell script?

Comment: What is `exec` in your code? [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)? Because it doesn't return a promise. So using `await` on it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `exec` looks like it takes a callback, you can use that to wrap it into a promise. Then you can await that promise instead of awaiting the `exec` call directly. So, for your example, something like:

```
// Await a new promise:
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec('./new_user_run_athena.sh ' + mongodbUserId, function(
        error,
        stdout,
        stderr
    ) {
        console.log('Running Athena...');
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            // Reject if there is an error:
            return reject(error);
        }

        // Otherwise resolve the promise:
        resolve();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See [the MDN documentation for `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

The `exec` function does not return a Promise, so you cannot await for it.

You could write a function [which wraps `exec` in a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) and returns that Promise though.

Comment: [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) can be handy here.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap **exec** in a promise. Here a typescript example:

```
import { exec as childProcessExec } from 'child_process'

const exec = async (command: string): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    childProcessExec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error !== null) reject(error)
      if (stderr !== '') reject(stderr)
      else resolve(stdout)
    })
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
const commandOutput = await exec('echo Hey there!')
console.log(commandOutput)
```